# Save as a image all the content of a grid

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, windows-phone-7, writeablebitmap

So, I'm trying to save an canvas content as an image. I'm using this for it:

```
var img = new WriteableBitmap(myCanvas, null);
```

Problem is that the image is not showing all the content inside of the canvas. If there's a button, an image or other similar objects, they do not show.

I can see an ellipse, but if I set an image as background, the background stays empty.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [Image Tools from codeplex](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) and read [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/braulio/archive/2009/07/12/export-canvas-to-png-and-save-it-in-your-local.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/10/12/saving-images-bmp-png-etc-in-wpf-silverlight.aspx)